# Return smallest combination of array elements to total to a number

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `$array` and a `$number`, and I want to find the smallest combination (least number of elements) of the `$array`'s elements, which sums to the `$number`, but I can't figure out how to do this with PHP code.

#### Test cases:

```
$array = [
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '3',
    'c' => '5',
    'd' => '5',
    'e' => '1',
    'f' => '2',
    'g' => '2',
];
```

If `$number = 10`, output should be `'c', 'd'`

If `$number = 1`, output should be either `'a'` or `'e'`

If `$number = 4`, output should be either `'a', 'b'` or `'b', 'e'` or `'f', 'g'`

If `$number = 9` output should be `'a', 'b', 'c'` or `'a', 'b', 'd'` or `'c', 'f', 'g'` etc.

How can I write this in code?

Comment: Are you only looking for couple ? Like 10 shouldn't get you c,d,f ?

Comment: I am looking for any number of combination using the least data

Comment: flip array and solve the problem of exchanging coins - i think there are some posts on stackoverflow

Comment: @nixonnixon please check my update

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
<?php
$array= array("a"=>"1", "b"=>"3", "c"=>"5", "d"=>"5", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2", "g"=>"2");
$num = 4;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $n1 = (int) $value;
    if ($n1 === $num) {
        echo $key.'<br/>';
        break;
    }

    if ($n1 < $num) {
        $n2 = $num - $n1;
        if ($n2Key = isN2Exists("$n2", $array)) { // this probably can also be done using some PHP built-ins, but I just couldnt find the right one
            echo "$key,$n2Key <br/>";
        }
    }
}

function isN2Exists($value, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($v === $value) {
            return $k;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This wont work if you need more than 2 numbers. For example, if the number is 9, you can not produce 9 with two numbers in your array. You need a,b,c or c,f,g. If you want it that way I think best way to do is to use recursion.

**Update**

If you want to do it through recursion, please try the following code. This should give you the exact output you are looking for:

```
<?php
$array= array("a"=>"1", "b"=>"3", "c"=>"5", "d"=>"5", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2", "g"=>"2");
$num = 9;

function getLeastNumbers($num, $array, $sum = 0, $level = '', $resultSet = [], $combination = []) {
    if ($sum > $num) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $n1 = (int) $value;

        if (($n1 + $sum) == $num) {

            $newCombination = $combination;
            $newCombination[] = $key;
            sort($newCombination);

            $resultSet[] = $newCombination;
        }

        $combinationToSend = $combination;
        $combinationToSend[] = $key;
        sort($combinationToSend);
        $array2 = $array;
        unset($array2[$key]);
        if ($return = getLeastNumbers($num, $array2, $n1 + $sum, "$level .", $resultSet, $combinationToSend)) {
            $resultSet = array_unique(array_merge($resultSet, $return), SORT_REGULAR);
        }
    }

    return $resultSet;
}

$list = getLeastNumbers($num, $array);

foreach($list as $item) {
    $length = count($item);
    $finalArray[$length][] = $item;
}


print_r($finalArray[min(array_keys($finalArray))]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ( and use Recursive Algorithm )

```
  <?php
$array= array("a"=>"1", "b"=>"3", "c"=>"5", "d"=>"5", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2","g"=>"2");$num=6;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if ($value==$num){
  echo $key."=>".$value."<br>";
  }
  echo "-----------------"."<br>";
  foreach( $array as $key1 => $value1) {
      if($key1 > $key){
          if(sumval($value,$value1)==$num){
              echo $key."=>".$key1."<br>";
          }
          elseif(sumval($value,$value1)<$num){
              $total=sumval($value,$value1);
              foreach( $array as $key2 => $value2) {
               if($key2 > $key1){
                   if(sumval($total,$value2)==$num){
                      echo $key."=>".$key1."=>".$key2."<br>";
                     } 
              }
          }
      }
  }
  }
}

function sumval($a,$b){
 return $a+$b;   
}

?>
```

Comment: This won't work if you need more than 3 numbers though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<?php
    $array = ["a"=>"1", "b"=>"3", "c"=>"5", "d"=>"5", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2", "g"=>"2"];
    $new = $array; 
    $number = 19;//Change here to check all condition 
    $flag = false;
    if(array_sum($new) == $number){
      $temp = array_keys($new);
      echo implode(",",$temp);
      $flag = true;
      exit;
    }
    if($flag)
      exit;

    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
      if($value == $number){
        echo $key."\n";
        $flag = true;
        exit;
      }
    }
    if($flag)
      exit;

    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
      $new = $array;
      array_pop($new);
      foreach($new as $key2=>$value2){
        if($key!=$key2){
          if(($value + $value2) == $number){
            echo "$key , $key2 \n";
            $flag = true;
            exit;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if($flag)
      exit;  

    $new = $array;
    foreach($array as $key1=>$value1){
      foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        $new = $array;
        unset($new[$key]);
        if(array_sum($new) == $number){
          $temp = array_keys($new);
          echo implode(",",$temp);
          exit;
        }
        array_pop($new);
      }
      array_pop($array);
    }

?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/897632